# Why doesn't the setInterval stop when the keyword 'return' is called?

Tags: javascript, return, settimeout, setinterval

I have a setInterval which is supposed to alert the amount of incremented `a` every 1 second only under a condition which is if `a <= 5`, else it should make `return a = 1`, which means it should turn `a` back to 1 and *stop the setInterval* from executing as initialized, but surprisingly it starts to execute the `setInterval` over and over again, each round with `a = 1` incrementng.

I want the setInterval to be executed only if `a <= 5` and as soon as this condition isn't true, then **stop** the `setInterval` and turn a back to 1, I don't want it to start the functoin over and over again, though it is turning `a` back to 1.

How can I make this happen?

```js
function doSomething() {

  let a = 1;

  foo = setInterval(() => {

    if (a <= 5) {
      a++;
      console.log(a)
    } else {
      return a = 1;
    }

  }, 1000)

  return 0;

}
setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);
```

Comment: A `return` is meaningless inside a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` (other than terminating the current function call). It doesn’t return anywhere. You stop the interval by calling `clearInterval(foo);`.

Comment: `return` just stops the current execution of a function. `setInteval` schedules regular executions. Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) with the interval ID to stop this schedule.

Comment: All of your function calls have a `return undefined` at the end implicitly. That doesn't stop the interval, and it might be intuitive to think returning truthy would, but that's not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it runs every interval. `return` just stops that iteration.

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Iterating")
}, 300)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 900)
```